# How to get the Commerce Product type from the order object. D7

Tags: 7, commerce

I am unable to find the product type when looking at the order object. I have tried

```
commerce_order_load($order_id);
```

This does not give the product type and neither does

```
commerce_line_item_load();
```

I have also looked for a function to achieve this [here](https://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21order%21commerce_order.module/7.56) but can't see anything to achieve this.

I am able to get the line item type it seems but not the product type, seems odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to load the product to be able to see the product type as this is not a property of the order or the line item.

For example (using entity metadata wrappers):

```
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
foreach($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item) {
  $type = $line_item->commerce_product->type->value();
  dpm($type, '$type');
}
```

Here is an example without using entity wrappers:

```
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
foreach($order->commerce_line_items[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $li) {
  $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($li['line_item_id']);
  $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['product_id']);
  $type = $product->type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just querying the database, here is what worked for me

```
$product_type = db_select('commerce_product', 'cp')
    ->fields('cp', array('type', 'product_id'))
    ->condition('cp.product_id', $product_id, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```